# Error while decompiling java class: ItemCollectionInvalidIndex: constants: requested 15873, limit 63

Tags: java, bytecode, decompiling

I am decompiling java application, and i have already done with 99% **.class** files. But, I have a problem with couple of them: error while decompilation (errors are same type).
Example:

**Procyon:** `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 'index' must be in the range [0, 63], but value was: 15873...`

**CFR:**

```
Can not load the class specified:
org.benf.cfr.reader.util.CannotLoadClassException: Modules_4.class - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Constant pool has 62 entries - attempted to access entry #30318
```

**JDCore:** returns null

**Jadx:**

```
ERROR - jadx error: Error load file: Modules_4.class
jadx.core.utils.exceptions.JadxRuntimeException: Error load file: Modules_4.class
at jadx.api.JadxDecompiler.loadFiles(JadxDecompiler.java:121)
at jadx.api.JadxDecompiler.load(JadxDecompiler.java:88)
at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.processAndSave(JadxCLI.java:34)
at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.main(JadxCLI.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 15873 out of bounds for length 63
```

**Fernflower:**

```
Job Output:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 15873 out of bounds for length 63
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)...
```

**JAD:**

```
Parsing Modules_4.class...The class file version is 50.0 (only 45.3, 46.0 and 47.0 are supported)
ItemCollectionInvalidIndex: constants: requested 15873, limit 63
```

[download .class file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K0qxedgfHW-x5fwy-WuflXERInJaBQKn/view?usp=sharing)

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried passing the class to `javap -v` to see if the class is even valid?

Comment: Error: unexpected end of file while reading. How can some classes be valid and others not in the same project?

Comment: “*How can some classes be valid and others not in the same project?*” By taking valid class files and invalid class files and stuffing them into one jar file. Why do you assume the validity of class files in a project has to be the same?

Comment: As the messages indicate, the class file declares to have 63 constant pool entries. An analysis of the file reveals that it actually has 152 entries, all other errors are follow-ups due to misinterpreting the data caused by to the wrong number right at the beginning of the file. But I can’t imagine, how buggy a program can be, to produce such a broken class file.

Comment: @Holger, Thanks a lot, I changed constant_pool_count to 152, it helped. But what kind of analysis did you do to find out how many cp structures are actually there?

Comment: Plausibility check. The next six bytes after the last constant pool entry must form the access flags, followed by indices for the actual class and the super class. These indices must be smaller than the number of constant pool entries. From the content of the first entries it was already clear that the numbers had to be `0x0002` and `0x0004` with a very high likelihood. In contrast when these numbers are not valid indices and the next byte after the last declared pool entry is between 1 and 20, it’s very likely the type of another pool entry. Then, just try to decode and if plausible, repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with all decompilers i have mentioned before.

It was a constant_pool_count issue. It happened because of some [JPHP decompiler](https://github.com/lonadels/JDecompiler) offset troubles. So, if you are trying to reverse jphp applications, use your own software to delim .phb to .class blocks with couple of bytes before each of them